# sof.modos.org update scripts

Tags: bug, status-completed

Recently, S triology update scripts have been constantly having problems displaying. The last two days they seem to have stopped working completely - is there a reason for that, or ... ?

(firefox 3.5 on xp)

Comment: Which "update scripts" are you talking about?

Comment: @Jon Skeet - for example; http://sof.modos.org/tracker/update/62699

Comment: Hmm, now it's called "reputation tracker", but for some reason I have it bookmarked as an "update script. Title changed ?

Comment: @ldigas: It was initially released as "update script" since it was a PHP script in one file. Once I put it in the CodeIgniter framework, I rebranded it as a reputation tracking service.

Comment: Ah, I see. Unfortunatelly, I don't know anything about this things (PHP, CodeIgniter), but if by any chance you find some time in the future to get it working again, I'd be really grateful. I use it daily, and consider it far superior to the implemented statistics page on the profile pages.

Answer (score 2):

I'm [the creator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9863/track-your-reputation) of the service you mention. It appears that modos.org's IP was somehow blacklisted. I sent an email to team@stackoverflow.com a little while ago and I'm waiting for a response.

Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

**edit:** Apparently there were some large requests that my site was pulling down. I've thrown in a limiter - 500 questions, 500 answers, sorted by activity. I may be able to creep this upward once I can get a better sense of how large these requests are. I've sent a reply detailing this, requesting to be unblocked, so now all I can do is wait for a reply.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the block is cleared now that we have

- user-agent properly set on the requests
- requests of a reasonable size
- http compression (gzip) on all requests

Answer (score 0):

If it relies on Yahoo Pipes, it might have something to do with this short twitter exchange:

http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/4436827424
http://twitter.com/simonw/status/4437114256
http://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/4437171439

Comment: it doesn't though